# Parsing nested dictionaries in Html (django)

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary

**Models.py**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    hometown =models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    
class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

**Views.Py**

```
def admin_main(request):
    Student_data = Student.objects.all()
    Subject_data = Subject.objects.all()
    Classes_data= Classes.objects.all()
    
    New_dict = {"Student_data":Student_data,
    "Subject_data",Subject_data,
    "Classes_data",Classes_data}

    return render(request,"admin_main.html",New_dict)
```

How to display all names from Student in admin_main.html

**admin_main.html**

Comment: I believe you forgot to add some of your code, you can [edit] to add it. Also your question is not very clear (potentially because of the missing code?) currently, can you clarify what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

#### admin_main.html

```html
{% for student in Student_data %}
  <p>{{student.name}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

- Here, we can display all the *students* by using the `for loop`

Comment: That worked. I wasn't sure that Student_data was still accessible in admin_main.html, since New_dict was passed as argument. Thanks a tonne.